# C++ sorting string depending on words frequency using function sort(), count() failed

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to sort a string depending on the words frequency.
For example:

- before: "tetees"
- after: "eeetts"

I chose to use sort() and count() function in algorithm.h like this:

```cpp
#include "bits/stdc++.h"

using namespace std;

string str="tetetafseaaaast";

bool cmp(char a, char b){
    return count(str.begin(), str.end(), a)>count(str.begin(), str.end(), b);
}

int main(){
    sort(str.begin(), str.end(), cmp);
    cout<<str<<endl;
}
```

However, the outcome is unsatisfying: "attetaaaaesetsf"

What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: do not include bits/anything

Comment: what does 'words frequency' mean for a random string of letters?

Comment: Tested here: [https://ideone.com/2XJ3rx](https://ideone.com/2XJ3rx)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::sort` does not guarantee that the string is in a consistent state when the comparator function is called. So your comparator function is not counting the same letters that are in the original string.

The following variation of your code does work.

```
struct Cmp
{
    Cmp(const string& s) : s(s) {}
    bool operator()(char a, char b) const
    {
        return count(s.begin(), s.end(), a) > count(s.begin(), s.end(), b);
    }
    string s;
};

int main()
{
    string str = "tetetafseaaaast";
    Cmp cmp(str);
    sort(str.begin(), str.end(), cmp);
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

The difference here is that the comparison is being done on a copy of the original string, not on the string that is in the process of being sorted.

Comment: Online version [https://ideone.com/bQhmYY](https://ideone.com/bQhmYY)

Comment: Thanks, it does work! But what does "a consistent state" mean, could you explain it more specific?

Comment: @Mightlaus What I mean is that it's not guaranteed at the time the comparison function is called that the string contains the same letters in the same frequency as the original string. The sorting code might be half way though a complicated swap and have some of the letters of the string in variables and have overwritten others.